# Draw GeoJSON on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Since I don't find the examples on the Leaflet site very useful, I tried to follow their general tips in order to draw my GeoJSON on map as a track. The thing is, the object is correctly saved, but when I add it to the map, it doesn't show anything. What am I missing here? I'm new to Leaflet. Thank you.

Code:

```
...

$.ajax('2016-05-04 13-13-36.gpx').done(function(response) {
    geo = toGeoJSON.gpx(response);
});

angular.element($elem[0]).append(angular.element('<div id="trackmap'+ trackmapCount +'" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 25px); border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>'));
trackmaps[trackmapCount] = new L.Map('trackmap'+ trackmapCount +'', {center: new L.LatLng(center[0], center[1]), zoom: 10});
var layer1 = osm.addTo(trackmaps[trackmapCount]);

L.geoJson(geo, {
style: myStyle
}).addTo(trackmaps[trackmapCount]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is an asynchronous method. This means that `geo` does not exist until the request completes and the `.done` callback function is called. You will need to create your `L.geoJson` object inside the callback:

```
$.ajax('2016-05-04 13-13-36.gpx').done(function(response) {
  geo = toGeoJSON.gpx(response);
  L.geoJson(geo, {
    style: myStyle
  }).addTo(trackmaps[trackmapCount]);
});
```